# 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, sqldatasource

I'm using `TemplateField` in `GridView` to implement `edit/delete` from database.

I'm Querying Data with the `SqlDataSource` Control.

when I edit the Table from page I get following error:

> 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does
>   not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

This is due to the data from dB is not matching any of the `DropDownList` Country name.

I understand the problem from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654220/has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in-the-list-of-it) (solution is not given there!)

I think when I insert data to dB, it automatically adds redundant spaces to data(like name of country)

So, one solution is to remove the spaces (Trim) from String so that value get matched in one of the `DropDownList` items.

because `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Country")%>'`
 doesn't match any list item of DropDownList

**but**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Country").ToString().Trim()%>'>
```

**matches the list item of DropDownList.**

**Now I want to update the data back to the database but instead of country name null value get stored.**
(I think it is the limitation of `Eval()`)

I can update the data back to the dB using `Bind()`
but `Bind` doesn't support `ToString().Trim()` so I can't trim the string to match one of the items from DropDownList.

How can I update back the data to dB?

my [raw code](http://ideone.com/q9gqyF)

Comment: Bind the `DropDownList1` Before Setting the `DataSource` To `GridView`.

show Your code , where you filling the GridView.

Comment: there you go http://ideone.com/q9gqyF

Comment: Try `SelectedItem='<%# Eval("Country").ToString().Trim()%>'`

Comment: @user3540365 SelectedItem didn't wrk..still null values

Comment: Still `Null value` Means??

Comment: Have you bind any values to the `DropDownList1` drodownlis?

Comment: @user3540365 I mean it update the country column field to null in dB

Comment: why you can't 'update the data back to the database', is there an error?

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta when I update the data back to the database it shows null in field rather than text.

Comment: @A_Sk your solution fixed my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scratching my head for several hours, finally, I found the elegant solution for the trailing spaces problem.

In my Table definition, In `Country` field definition I was using `nchar(100)` instead of `nvarchar(100)`. The former always has 100 characters (thus the trailing spaces), the later can have up to 100 characters, but doesn't fill up the space (thus matches the item in `DropDownlist`).

In nutshell, `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Country")%>'>`  is working fine now.

*I hope it helps future readers.*

Comment: Thank you very much. I made the same mistake, until I read this post and cleared the trailing spaces in the database table.

Answer (score 2):

> "So, one solution is to remove the spaces (Trim) from String so that
>   value get matched in DropDownList fields."

I'm a little confused as to why this would make a difference.

Could you show us the raw HTML which this DropDownList control has created, and which row you're attempting to edit.

To view the raw HTML..

- Open your webpage in Chrome
- Hit F12 to show Developer Options
- Now, right-click on the Drop Down List on your webpage, and select "Inspect Element"
- In the Elements tab of Chrome's Developer window, you'll see a `select` element, which ASP.Net has created for you.  Expand this element, to see the `option` elements.
- Have a look down the value attributes for each of these.

You should see a more complicated version of this...

```
<select id="listOfPeople">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="10">Mike</option>
   <option value="17">Geoffery</option>
   <option value="18">Edward</option>
</select>
```

... and the error you're seeing suggests that when you click on one of the rows, its value isn't matching one of the `value`s listed in the `option`s.

**Update**

After looking at your .aspx file, I see that you display a list of Country names, but none have a Value:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Country").ToString().Trim()%>'>
    <asp:ListItem>Select Country</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>UK</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>China</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>North Korea</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Kazakhstan</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Shouldn't they look like this...

```
<asp:ListItem Value="North Korea">North Korea</asp:ListItem>
```

...rather than this...?

```
<asp:ListItem>North Korea</asp:ListItem>
```

(Again - use Chrome to check whether your drop down list of country names *do* have a `Value` in them.  If they don't, this will explain the error you're seeing.)

**Update 2**

I'm stealing the following tip from one of the many other StackOverflow questions which have asked this same question:

Try adding the following into your `edittemplate` to see the current value:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCountryName" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
```

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502905/how-to-fix-ddlassignedto-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does)

This should tell you the `Value` it's trying to look for, and cannot find, in the list of `option` items, created by your DropDownList control.

Comment: here's  my code http://ideone.com/q9gqyF and dropdown list shows  only when i cick on the edit button

Comment: See the "Update" to my answer above.

Comment: for country china i'm getting this from chrome <span id="GridView1_Label5_1">China                                             </span>

Comment: and i updated the code to <asp:ListItem Value="North Korea">North Korea</asp:ListItem> for all fields but still same problem

Comment: and there's no benefit to use Eval() because i can't update the value back to dB

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Country"))%>'>
 <asp:ListItem Value="">Select Country</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="India">India</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="USA">USA</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="UK">UK</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="China">China</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="North Korea">North Korea</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItemValue="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: we have to trim the spaces too!

Comment: Can you Say what `Eval("Country")` getting the Value??

Comment: I think it is getting the string but with redundant spaces becuz '<%# Eval("Country").ToString().Trim()%>' runs smoothly.

Comment: Debug you code and See what's value `Eval("Country")` getting,while binding the GridView.

Comment: how can I see value from Eval("Country") ?

Answer (score 0):

Because values are not same male/Male and female/Female. Its case problems.

```html
       <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
```

```html
     <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>male</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>female</asp:ListItem>
```