# Populate dropdown list with value that does not exist?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Regarding this error I am getting:

Exception message: 'DropDown' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

I have 2 asp.net pages, one is a search page that a search can be done based on a user. The other is a results page. If the user is no longer with us and is removed from a drop down list on the results page but we still want to have them searchable, is it possible to somehow tell the drop down list to use the value "Other" if it does not exist in the results page drop down?

I tried something like this but it is still telling me the value does not exist?

```
            Try
                DropDown.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString("User")
            Catch ex As Exception
                DropDown.SelectedValue = "Other"
            End Try
```

Is there a way to get around loading a value in a dropdown list if it doesn't previously exist? TIA

Comment: It seems to be a lifecycle problem. Could you please post the complete code of the page? It seems that you are populating the dropdown in the wrong place.

Comment: The source is a SQL datasource for each dropdown. Both read the same user table and I set active or inactive in a column to do the filtering

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502905/how-to-fix-ddlassignedto-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does) will help. The code you provided in the question doesn't help to figure out the problem, we cannot see the events how one page calls another etc.

Comment: Thank you, maybe there is a way to just check the dropdown list if the value exists if not use "this value"

Comment: By definition dropdown list needs the selectedvalue to be an existing item in the list. So if you set it to a non existing item you get the error. The solution is to add the item you want to be selected BEFORE setting selectedvalue property. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2). The ONLY WAY to set the selectedvalue property is to have a corresponding item in the list.

Comment: thank you for your help